# How do I improve existing typings without my own project without completely removing them

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm currently working on a project which uses the `@aws-amplify/auth` package to work with AWS Cognito. Problem is, although the package does include types, they are a bit... well... rubbish.

So within my project, I'd like to augment the types in a way that is globally available for everyone in the `nx` monorepo. So far I've done the following

- Create a `./types/aws-amplify__auth` package that has an `index.d.ts` file in it
- Changed `tsconfig.base.json` to include the `./types` folder in `typeroots`
- Added `"aws-amplify__auth"` to the `types` property within the project actually using the global definition
- Added the following code to `./types/aws-amplify__auth/index.d.ts`

```
declare module '@aws-amplify/auth' {
  interface SignInResponse {
    username: string;
    // ...More stuff
  }

  class AuthClass {
    signIn(config: {
      username: string;
      password: string;
    }): Promise<SignInResponse>;
  }

  export const Auth: AuthClass
}
```

Now this works... sort of. But what it does is *override* the types being imported by the module. Ideally, I'd like not to have to redeclare functions that are already typed sensibly (and risk my augmentations being even more brittle). I was under the impression that it was possible to [*merge* declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), but I'm not quite sure how to do it here.

Comment: Ima go ahead and bump this because I'm also interested in how to non-destructively add types. Hopefully this lets me know when you get an answer lol.

Comment: COuld you please provide reproducible example and comment desired an undesired behavior. It will be easier to answer this question